# Not understanding how pointers and classes work together in this example

Tags: c++, arrays, class, pointers, dereference

Hmmmm I am stumped on this one, using Visual Studio 2012 I have only one error left on my project and I am dying to test it out. Yes it's for a C++ class and I hope I posted enough code.

I get the error:

C2227 left of ->writeData must point to class/struct/union/generic type

In the previous project this line had the element of the array of pointers ( an Employee* pointer I assume) and it worked like so:

```
Employee* myEmployees[MAX_EMPS];
...
myEmployees[i]->writeData(outputEmployee);
```

So I implement a vector of Employee*, and assume it also contains pointers:

```
MyVector<Employee*> employeePtrList;
```

I do the next couple steps a bit indirectly but have cleared this with Prof. Debry:

```
Employee* empPtr1 = new HourlyEmployee(EMP1_ID, EMP1_NAME, EMP1_ADDRESS, EMP1_PHONE, EMP1_HOURS, EMP1_WAGE);
2...
3...
4...

employeePtrList.push_back(empPtr1);
2...
3...
4...
```

Then later in the program this line is giving me the error:

```
employeePtrList.at(i)->writeData(outputEmployee);
```

I have tried various things, if I dereference it with *(employeePtrList) just for fun it changes the intellisense error but I still get the same:

C2227 left of ->writeData must point to class/struct/union/generic type

Any idears? Where I get stumped is understand that employeePtrLIst is an Employee pointer so maybe it's looking for at in the wrong class? I guess maybe I am not "pointing" to the function in the MyVector class properly?

Thanks

Comment: What does `employeePtrList.at(i)` return?

Comment: If you are asking in theory, I would assume a pointer to the Employee class, in practice this will not run. I guess I need to figure out how to form that so it returns something from the MyVector class where the member function exists?

Comment: What is MyVector<> Is it really a vector with an .at function?

Comment: Shrink your example down to the smallest runnable code that demonstrates the problem and post that. You may even discover the problem yourself while doing this.

Comment: It's a class with .at as a member function, yes. It acts like a vector with a push_back function as well as getters and setters.

Comment: And does the at() return a pointer? If this is a class of your own, you should check that, because it looks reasonable to me

Comment: are you including the header in your source file?

Comment: OK thanks for all your help I think you have all given me the nudge I needed. The project is supposed to use our vector class and polymorphism in some employee classes, I will post the answer when I figure it out, thanks!

Comment: You forgot to include the header that actually defines Employee. You can't call functions on a forward declared class

Comment: Hey I want to thank everyone, and especially for not jumping on me for not posting enough info. Turns out Johnny Mopp, with the first answer, was on the right track. I was not returning a pointer from employeePtrList.at(i) and when I changed that return type to be a pointer everything started falling into place.

Comment: So if I had advice for another newb looking at this conversation, just because you are passing a pointer to a function doesn't mean it will return a pointer, unless you explicitly make the return type a pointer by putting the * after it. Duh. Problem solved thanks all and I will post a better question next time! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without knowing exactly how `MyVector` works, a few things at first glance could be going wrong:

`.at()` might be returning a reference to an object (or even a copy of the object), thus you'd need to use the `.` operator.

Another possibility is that, if `.at()` returns an iterator of type `Employee*`, you might need to dereference the iterator (i.e. `(*employeePtrList.at(i))->writeData(outputEmployee);`) *depending on the implementation*.

Comment: Thanks Qix you had it right as well, great info! I am too new to upvote it (said shamefully lol)

Comment: Hey @provoutah - Just letting you know you're welcome to accept an answer if it helped you out!